# php Warning: require(): Filename cannot be empty

Tags: php

this is index.php

```
<?php
  require 'core/bootstrap.php';
  require Router::load('routes.php')->direct(Request::uri());
```

this is Router.php

```
<?php

class Router
  {
    protected $routes = [];

public static function load($file)
{
    $router = new static;

    require $file;

    return $router;
}

public function define($routes)
{
    $this->routes = $routes;
}

public function direct($uri)
{
    if (array_key_exists($uri, $this->routes)) {
        return $this->routes[$uri];
    } 

}
}
```

> Warning: require(): Filename cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\index.php on line 6
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\index.php on line 6

I'm getting this error.

Comment: Obviously `Router::load('routes.php')->direct(Request::uri())` is returning empty string, so you're trying to do `require ''`.

Comment: my friend I know what does filename cannot be empty error means I need any suggestions how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is calling the function `direct` inside your router.

```
public function direct($uri)
```

If the route defined by `$uri` is not found then the function returns nothing.
So when you are calling the following with an invalid route:

```
require Router::load('routes.php')->direct(Request::uri());
```

You are actually calling

```
require;
```

This will result in the `empty filename` error.

Comment: The value returned by ‘’Request::uri()’’ needs to match one of the values passed in by ‘’routes.php’’.  I would echo out the value returned by ‘’Request::uri()’’ and then see if it matched anything.